# java, I get symbol instead of number like this ������

Tags: java

i get temperature from serial port ,which gives symbols instead number .

```
 try {
                    while (inputStream.available() > 0) {
                        int n = inputStream.available();
                        readBuffer = new byte[n];
                        inputStream.read(readBuffer, 0, n);
                    }
                    int i=1;
                    String y = new String(readBuffer, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
                    String str = new String(readBuffer, "UTF-8");

                    String ye = new String(readBuffer);
                    String b = new BigInteger(1, readBuffer).toString();
                    jTextField3.setText("    " + str + "    ");
```

Comment: this is binary data

Comment: Well, for one thing, you are reading what looks like 6 bytes, which isn't a length I'd expect for "a" number. What is the wire format in which the data is written?

Comment: please help to get binary to string

Comment: try {
                    while (inputStream.available() > 0) {
                        int n = inputStream.available();
                        readBuffer = new byte[n];
                        inputStream.read(readBuffer, 0, n);
                    }
                    int i=1;
                    String y = new String(readBuffer, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
                    String str = new String(readBuffer, "UTF-8");
                    String b = new BigInteger(1, readBuffer).toString();
                    jTextField3.setText("    " + str + "    ");

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your `inputStream` in a [`DataInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html), and then use the [`readByte()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readByte()), [`readInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readInt()) methods as appropriate to read the correct type of data from the stream.

Comment: youtube.com/watch?v=hteeNdA7pOo in this video , it works fine but why i need symbols , please help me sir

Answer (score 1):

This is because the serial port gives you the values in binary, not text. You need to find the exact format of the values (2 or 4 bytes, signed or unsigned, ...) in order to convert them correctly to string.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hteeNdA7pOo in this video , it works fine but why i need symbols , please help me sir

Answer (score 0):

Now `available()` is for asychrone polling, and could be 0 before yield a positive count. Best would be to read the buffer in blocking manner.

```
 byte[] readBuffer = new byte[0];
 try {
     for (;;) {
          int n = inputStream.available();
          if (n <= 0) {
              break;
          }
          readBuffer = new byte[n];
          inputStream.read(readBuffer, 0, n);
          break;
     }
     String y = new String(readBuffer, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
     jTextField3.setText("    \"" + y + "\"    ");
     jTextField3.setText(Arrays.toString(readBuffer)));
  }
```

The encoding was missing for your bytes. And best probably is to keep the data as byte array.

Comment: Why have the loop here? You break unconditionally. And does this really change anything? The problem doesn't appear to be that  no data is available; data is read, it just can't be interpreted as a string's bytes in the default charset.

Comment: @AndyTurner I made the code intentionally ugly, because testing `available()` is normally not good style. Perhaps unless looping and collecting fragments of a fixed size buffer. It could deliver 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 8, 1. Serial port having an unknown behavior to me - I would not wonder receiving first thousands of zeroes. **My code is no effective solution.**

Comment: "øøøøøø"    your code gives me this symbol , please help me

Comment: Serial port processing is rather low-level. I am afraid you won't get an adequate answer here, it depends on the exact use-case. You could make a busy loop, inside read the then-available bytes, and dump their int (hex) value (not as char, text) to console and file. Then you at least see the real communication. Search more technical sources.